# Request - Response pattern with Async .Net Sockets library

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous

I have created async library that currently is able to exchange single packets between server and client. Now I am trying to design mechanism that will handle packets in "Request-Response" fashion.

To be more precise lets look at this scenario:

1. Client sends **GiveMeFile** packet
2. Server receives it and instantly replies with **HereIsYourFile** response packet
3. Client receives this rssponse and saves the file

In step 2. it is important for client to expect a response and this respons must be received in specific time.

I was thinking about some kind of queue for "expected" responses, that would be cleared of every received response, but I am not sure if this is good approach.

Do you have any suggestions how to implement asynchronous Request-Response pattern?

Comment: You should improve your question with a few details: do your commands have to be versatile or constant, e.g. I have "giveMeInt" and "giveMeString" commands and if I want to implement more, I just add "giveMeBytes" to the possible commands list and make a response to that. That makes it easier to understand which way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a high performance TCP Server using [SocketAsyncEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.aspx). You can Google around about it but there is a not so old article on it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83102/C-SocketAsyncEventArgs-High-Performance-Socket-Cod) which still is useful. `SocketAsyncEventArgs` totally worked for me to design a concurrent TCP Server.